# React.createElement: type is invalid when using array.map inside a stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";

const BasicDetail = ({DetailData}) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <Grid.Row>
                <h3>Basic Details</h3>
                {DetailData.map((form) => {
                     return (
                         <Form.input
                             label={form.label}
                             readOnly={true}
                             defaultValue={form.default}
                            type="text"
                         />
                     )
                 })}
            </Grid.Row>
        </div>
    )
}

BasicDetail.propTypes = {
    DetailData: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default BasicDetail;
```

I am passing it an array of objects in props, but I am getting the following error:

> warning.js:36 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method
>   of `BasicDetail`.

If I remove the .map function from the component it renders correctly.

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Semantic UI React` components names starts with capital letter.
Use `Form.Input`  instead of `Form.input`.